# Prove or disprove with $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\ \varphi \ v_{n}$ the existence $V$ with $V_{n}\overset{d}{\rightarrow} V ,n\rightarrow \infty$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Prove or disprove with $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\ \varphi_{V_n}$ the existence of a random variable $V$ with $V_{n}\overset{d}{\rightarrow} V ,n\rightarrow \infty$.

$V_n$ is a sequence of random variables with $V_n \sim \text{unif}(-n,n) ,n\in \mathbb{N},  \varphi_{V_n}: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ the characteristic function of $V_n, n\in \mathbb{N}$.

I was reading many articles about the topics but I still have no idea how could I start to solve the exercise above. I have tried to construct a counterexample without any success I would appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ch.f. of $V_n$ is given by
$$
\varphi_{V_n}(t)=\frac{e^{itn}-e^{-itn}}{2itn}, \quad t\ne 0,
$$
and $\varphi_{V_n}(0)=1$. For $t\ne 0$, $\varphi_{V_n}(t)\to 0$, which means that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\varphi_{V_n}(t)=1_{\{0\}}(t)$ is discontinuous at $0$. (See [Lévy's continuity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%27s_continuity_theorem).)

Comment: Could you tell me how can I get the ch.f.? I don't understand the very first step. Thank you in advance

Comment: @Herrpeter
$$
\varphi_{V_n}(t)=\mathsf{E}e^{it V_n}=\int_{-n}^n \frac{e^{it x}}{2n}\, dx.
$$